# How to average # of parks per child within 1 sq mile and average parks per child in whole county?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, field-calculator, attribute-table

I have a shapefile of census tracts within Cook County, IL that has been combined with a shapefile of every park in the cook county area. It displays as a graduated color scheme of number of parks per tract. On top of that, I have a dot layer from the that displays the number of children per census tract in the county. Each dot represents 500 known children. I'm trying to form a poster that displays the relative access that children have to parks in the county. As the project stipulates having supporting graphs, tables and statistics, I would like to display the average amount of parks available to a child in contrast to the average amount of parks per child in the county. I will attach a snippet of the map for reference.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour], which explains how our Focused question/Best answer model operates. Questions here are expected to show some effort toward solving the task, along with details of an error or problem encountered along the way.

Comment: I understand. I'm still a very new student in ArcGIS, as this is my first class. I just don't know how to create a query that relates the two variables of children and number of parks to the spatial variable of being in range of one square mile. I'll head back to the drawing board. Thanks.